# How to convert date field in response from string in vuejs so that I can group by based on other columns

Tags: vue.js, charts, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I need to send the response date function to the X coordinate of my graph and for this, I need this column in date format. I tried to convert using momentjs, it is in date format initially, but when I push this to another array, it is converting to string again.
How to push the date format data to the array and use it in X-coordinate.

```
<script>
import { getAPI } from '../axios-api'
import Chart from "../components/ChartJS.vue";
import moment from "moment";
export default{
name : 'ChartVis',
data: () => {
  return {
    chartData: [],
    labels:[],
  };
},
components:{
        Navbar,
        Chart,
    },
 mounted () {
        this.getData()
    },
methods: {
  async getData(){
    
     await getAPI.get('/summary')
        .then((response) => {

            this.labels = (response.data.map(item => parseFloat(item.length_max)))

          response.data.forEach(item => {
            const newDate = moment(item.date).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
            console.log(newDate)
            changedDate.push(newDate)
          });

          

          this.chartData=changedDate
          console.log(changedDate)
          console.log(this.labels)
          })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
          })

  },

  },
}
</script>
```

Both before pushing to the array and after pushing is shown in the image
[image: date]

Using it as a string, I am able to draw a chart, but how to group by based on other columns and draw the chart.

Answer (score 1):

Moment's `format` function converts a `Date` to a string. [See here.](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/01-format/) Therefore, the `changedDate` array only contains strings.

You can store both the original `Date` value (`item.date`) with the formatted value (`newDate`) in an object, and modify the chart to use one for the column binding, and the other for display purposes. For example:

```
changedDate.push({
  dateValue: item.date,
  dateString: newDate
});
```

Then change the chart code accordingly (if possible).

*Alternatively,* most chart components offer different properties for display vs. binding data, or at least, a way to specify the format. If this is the case, you can leave your code the same and change a prop somewhere in the chart.

Comment: Thank you, I am able to display the graph with the data format as a string. 
Is there a way to use this string function to group by based on other columns? As you can see, there are repeated dates, I have one more column, which is a location (string), Based on that I need to display different lengths in a line graph.

Comment: I'm happy to help with your question regarding the lengths, but could you please accept/upvote my answer on this one and then edit your question (or post a new one)? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I will update the post. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: I have also posted a new question specifically, if possible please help me out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68656213/vuejs-how-to-group-by-based-on-response-data-columns

Answer (score 0):

Now that since you say that you want to display the date in date format  on the column in a format you require, I think using date pipe while displaying would serve your purpose.
May be this can help.

```
import moment from 'moment'

Vue.filter('formatDate', function(value) {
  if (value) {
    return moment(String(value)).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
  }
}
```

And you can use it like `{{ yourdate | formatDate }}`