# VueJS : How to group by based on response data columns

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I need to send the response date function to the X coordinate of my graph and for this, I need this column in date format (with the string it is working fine).If it is okay to draw by keeping the date column as string, it'd be good, but for grouping at least this has to be converted is what I think. There are repeated dates coming from the bank end, I need to group by based on the other response data, which is location. How can this be achieved and how can I display the line chart for this based on the Location column

**My code**

```
<script>
import { getAPI } from '../axios-api'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar.vue';
import custChart from "../components/ChartJS.vue";
// import moment from "moment";
export default{
name : 'ChartVis',
data: () => {
  return {
    chartData: [
      {
        label : 'length_max',
        backgroundColor: '#FC2525',
        data:[]
      },
      {
        label : 'length_min',
        backgroundColor: '#05CBE1',
        data:[]
      },
      {
        label : 'length_avg',
        backgroundColor: '#EC2525',
        data:[]
      },
      {
        label : 'length_std',
        backgroundColor: '#DC2525',
        data:[]
      },
      {
        label : 'location',
        backgroundColor: '#DC2525',
        data:[]
      },
    ],
    labels:[],
    loaded : false,
  };
},
components:{
        Navbar,
        custChart,
    },
 mounted () {
        this.loaded = false
        this.getData()
    },
methods: {
  async getData(){
    
     await getAPI.get('datavisualisation/summary')
        .then((response) => {
          

            this.chartData[0] = (response.data.map(item => parseFloat(item.length_max)))
            this.chartData[1] = (response.data.map(item => parseFloat(item.length_min)))
            this.chartData[2] = (response.data.map(item => parseFloat(item.length_avg)))
            this.chartData[3] = (response.data.map(item => parseFloat(item.length_std)))
            this.chartData[4] = (response.data.map(item => (item.location)))
            this.labels = response.data.map(item => item.date)
          this.loaded = true
          })
          
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
          })

  },

  },
}
</script>
```

**Repeated Dates**
[image]

**Other columns**

[image]

**my Graph**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i can't find a problem anywhere in your question. Do you mean grouped together as in you want the array to be sorted? what kind of chart are you making? Do you want multiple data points on the same day and why?

Comment: Thank you, I have added the graph also, the problem is, the X-coordinated Date columns are repeated, instead, I want it to be displayed on group based on Tank (location) data. My question was related to it. Yes, I need array to be sorted. I am making bar and line charts based on date column adn group by location

Comment: @Shekarshekar are you making a [Stacked Bar Chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/stacked.html) or do you just want to sort the bars by Tank? So if there are points with the same Tank, are they on top of each other or next to each other? Do you want the bars to be in groups of tanks. and within those groups sorted by date? How does the line chart tie into all of this? This seems really complicated for something that probably isn't that complicated.

Comment: Apologies, if my question was not clear. I am not trying out the stacked bar chart. I am trying grouped bar charts and line charts for a different sets of data. 
Grouped Bar chart: There are 3 date columns if you observe my data, I need to display def_percent on these 3 dates, grouped by Tank (location) data. On 01/01 Tank 1, Tank 2 and Tank 5 grouped data and so on. This goes the same for line chart, in which Y-coordinate data will be length_max, length_min, length_avg, length_std.